# Delete the first line after the specific word (COMPDAT) only if this first line contains "1 1" with Python

Tags: python

I asked the similar question [How to delete one line after the specific word with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587628/how-to-delete-one-line-after-the-specific-word-with-python) . However, I want to add one more condition. So I want to have two conditions to delete the first line:

1. After the word "COMPDAT".
2. Only if this first line contains "1" for item 4 and 5.

For example:

COMPDAT

'9850' 125 57 ***1 1*** OPEN /

The code suggested in my previous question works only for condition 1:

```
input_file = open("input.txt", 'r')
prev_line = False
lines =[]
for line in input_file:
 if not prev_line:
    lines.append(line)
 prev_line=False
 if "COMPDAT" in line:
    prev_line=True
input_file.close()

input_file = open("input.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
   input_file.write(line)
input_file.close()
```

How to change this code in order to satisfy also the second condition?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679201/7486016)

```
def line_and_line_before(file):
    prev_line = None
    for line in file:
        yield (prev_line, line)
        prev_line = line

def has_ones(line):
    splitted_line = line.split(" ")
    return len(splitted_line) > 4 and splitted_line[3] == '1' and splitted_line[4] == '1'

input_file = open("input.txt", 'r')
lines = []

for prev_line, line in line_and_line_before(input_file):
     if (not prev_line or "COMPDAT" not in prev_line) or not has_ones(line):
         lines.append(line)

input_file.close()

input_file = open("input.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
    input_file.write(line)
input_file.close()
```

You need to think in terms of *when to keep line* instead of *when to remove line*.

Comment: thank you. I have an error when I run this code: "indexerror: list index out of range". How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You could modify the `has_ones` function to check if `splitted_line` is long enough.

Comment: Could you, please, advise how to make it properly? Addition of "if len(splitted_line) > 3:" doesn't help me. Thank you!

Comment: It's because we also access item 4, so you have to check `len(splitted_line) > 4`. let me edit to show another possibility.

Comment: Here it is. `len(splitted_line) > 4 and ...` will return `False` without evaluating the rest of the line if evaluated to `False`.

Comment: There was an error there : `if (not prev_line or "COMPDAT" not in prev_line) and not has_ones(line):` `and` should have been `or`. Edited.

Comment: Thank you! this is a perfect solution!